# How do I render an HTML5 animation in a native iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, html, animation, uiwebview

I am trying to work with an HTML5 animator on an iPhone app. He proposes that we use HTML5 to implement the animations.

As I have never done this before, is it possible for iOS to work with HTML5? Do I just use `UIWebView` to render the animations?

Comment: If we’re being picky, animations are part of Apple’s extensions to CSS (which may become part of CSS3), rather than HTML5. However, Apple has used HTML5 as an umbrella term for anything newish that you can do in Safari, so we probably shouldn’t be picky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to crate an UIWebView, but keep in mind that the iPhone has limited amount of memory an CPU, if the animation will be complex I will render slow.

To render more complex animation I suggest using [Quartz 2D](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html)